# trouble with downloading video file from azure blob storage using video file url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to download video file from azure blob storage using file-saver npm module. you can see my code  [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/filesaver-forked-07rtv?file=/src/index.js) what i have exatly done. I want to start download blob video file on download button click but file-saver firstly downloads file internally and then after download it shows save as window and this process is fine for small size files but if file size will large its  not good experience to user. please suggest to download video file from blob using video url.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";

import "./styles.css";

const onDownload = async () => {
  console.log("download start");
  let blob = "media-url"
      saveAs(blob, "video.mp4");
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={onDownload}>Download</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Comment: video is downloaed but not playing, it's currupted

Comment: let me check, pls wait.

Comment: okay, check with your own blob file url and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

## Update

**vijay kasar's comment is very correct, I will update my answer.**

The download process is carried out through the onDownloadProgress method, and then after the download is finished, the callback uses the response for data processing. The saveAs function in file-saver looks like an internal download operation. [It is better to support the callback method](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/335). If you are interested, you can also check the official documentation. Because you don't know file-saver, axios is recommended.

```
axios({
    url: 'MediaUrl',
    responseType:'blob',
    onDownloadProgress(progressEvent) {
        progress = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100);

        setPercentage(progress);

        documentStyles.setProperty('--progress', `${progress}%`);
    }
}).then(response => {
        setProgress('finished');
        const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = downloadUrl;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'video.mp4'); //any other extension
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        link.remove();
});
```

**It is recommended to use `axios` to download, use `onDownloadProgress` to increase the user experience of downloading.**

*Related blog*:
**[How to Make a Download Progress Indicator in React](https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/how-to-make-a-download-progress-indicator-in-react-7b2e31211504)**

You can [download my modified test code](https://github.com/Jason446620/react-fetch-progress) based on the sample code in the blog for reference.

## Test renderings (`.gif`) and code :

[image]

[image]

```
const download = () => {
    const documentStyles = document.documentElement.style;
    let progress = 0;

    setProgress('in-progress');

    axios({
        url: 'MediaUrl',
        onDownloadProgress(progressEvent) {
            progress = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100);

            setPercentage(progress);

            documentStyles.setProperty('--progress', `${progress}%`);
        }
    }).then(response => {
        setProgress('finished');
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'video.mp4'); //or any other extension
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
    });
};
```

Comment: this answer is worked for me after adding response type(responseType: "blob"), in axios request.

Comment: @vijaykasar I have updated my answer, mylatest answer explains the reason for your problem, because I am not very familiar with react or javascript, so I can only give you a general idea.